# Why won't jquery .next and .toggle not work here

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

I'm wondering if the .next and .toggle in jQuery has changed with the latest releases.
The code I have used to work and there have been no changes to that code.

The script:(it s supposed to open submenus)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dropdown-submenu a.HasDropDown').on("click", function(e) {
    $(this).next('ul').toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    //alert("menu clicked");
  });
});
```

```html
<li class="dropdown-submenu">
  <a style="color: gainsboro; background-color: black !important;" href="/EntityPersonAddress/List">
         Addresses
     </a>
</li>

<li class="dropdown-submenu">
  <span>
         <a class="HasDropDown" style="color: gainsboro; background-color: black !important;" href="#">
         XX Management
         </a>
     </span>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
      <a style="color: gainsboro; background-color: black !important;" href="/TCO/Edit">
          TCO
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
      <a style="color: gainsboro; background-color: black !important;" href="/Report/TCO">
          TCO Reports
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selector you use is not good, [see this working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amfp8jhz/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dropdown-submenu a.HasDropDown').on("click", function(e) {
    $(this).parent().next('ul').toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    //alert("menu clicked");
  });
});
```

The `.dropdown-menu` element is in the same level as the parent of `.HasDropDown` (which is the `span` element.